# Sliding finger UIImageView

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiimageview, touch, swipe

How do you detect when you slide your finger across a UIImageView?  Say for example you slide your finger across it and it changes color or something.  I want to be able to slide across multiple UIImageViews and have something happen...

Answer (score 0):

Try a `UIImageView` within a `UIScrollView`!

To detect your touchs in a `UIImageView` you have to rewrite a `UIImageView` and set `UserInteractionEnabled` to `YES`. Then you can handle events like `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`.

**UIImageWithTouchControl.h**

```
@interface UIImageWithTouchControl : UIImageView
```

**UIImageWithTouchControl.m**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}
```